# Значение слова "механистический"

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, значение-слов

> Можно ли сказать "механистическое движение"?
>   (То есть свойственное неживому объекту: механизму, машине, роботу.)

Answer (score 3):

"**Механистический**" - характеристика стиля *мышления* или подхода к объяснению чего-либо сложного. В узком смысле и исторически это означало *перенесение законов механики* на непознанные явления. Например, ранние *представления* о Вселенной были *механистическими*, поскольку пояснялись с позиций хорошо развитой механики, основанной на законах Ньютона. К описанию свойств реальных объектов термин "механистический" (вместо механического) не применяется.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сказать: **механистические законы/принципы  движения** не следует применять  для описания немеханичеких систем (например, природы, живой материи).

Наверное, можно сказать:  нельзя понимать движение живой материи как **механистическое движение**.

**Из словаря:**

**МЕХАНИСТИЧЕСКИЙ**,  Основанный на принципах механицизма. М. материализм. М-ая теория. М-ое направление. <Механистически, нареч.

**МЕХАНИЦИЗМ,** -а; м. Философское учение, широко распространённое в 17 - 18 вв., объясняющее развитие природы и общества законами механики, а всё многообразие мира - механическим движением однородных частиц материи. Идеи механицизма.

**Примеры:**

Усвоив взгляды Галилея и Декарта на природу, Томас Гоббс попытался применить **механистические законы движения** к социальным системам. [ «Геоинформатика», 2002.06.26]

Полет «Бурана» показал, что летающие машины, в которых заложен **механистический принцип,** достигли предела развития.

И психология и нейронауки настолько продвинулись в своем развитии, что ... **механистические представления** о работе мозга можно считать по большому счету уже преодоленными. [«Вопросы психологии», 2004.04.13]